# CakePHP generate a Document to Webroot

Tags: cakephp, ms-word

I'm currently working with cakephp and I am generating a word document. My problem is how can I put the generated document on my web root and not as a download.

Comment: Your questions is too vague. You should either explain more or copy some code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are using an action to generate a document, which gets output to the browser.

You should either use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to "catch" the output and then write it to a file, or write the document data to a string, and write that string to a file on the server.

EDIT:
PHPWord has a SAVE method. In your action, you can save the document to a certain location, but output something else, i.e. success notification. This way, your action **only generates** the file:

```
public function generateWordDocument(){
//... your word file creation...
    $wordDocumentLocation = TMP . 'word_files/';
    $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save($wordDocumentLocation . 'helloWorld.docx');
    $this->Session->setFlash('Document generated!');
    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index')); //or wherever you want
}
```

If you want to protect that file, you could save the file to a "secure" folder (this can either be a folder outside the "app/webroot" folder, or a folder protected with .htaccess deny all instruction) and than use another action, like "getWordDocument":

```
function getWordDocument($documentName){
    $wordDocumentLocation = TMP . 'word_files/';
    if (file_exists($wordDocumentLocation . $documentName)) { //this is not really the safest way of doing it
         $fp = fopen($wordDocumentLocation . $documentName, 'rb');
         header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
         header("Content-Length: " . filesize($wordDocumentLocation . $documentName));
         fpassthru($fp);
         exit();
    }
}
```

Please note, that this code is just for "grasping the concept" and is in no way safe or optimal.

Comment: yeah thats right.. and i am using phpword to generate the document and it works fine as of the moment except the addimage function

Comment: Again, please try adding more info in the question next time you post anywhere. It makes answering so much easier.

Comment: does it really need to save in TMP??

Comment: Of course not, I just used it as an example what you *could* do. If you want your documents to be publicly available to anyone with a link to it, you should put it somewhere inside app/webroot and just give the user a link to that file to download it.
If you wish to restrict access to those files (for instance, only registered users can download), you can do it through a controller action and then you can save files wherever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to add file in webroot but it is not downloadable for public users ,
You have several ways :
 - protect folders with .htaccess (Like Js folder)
 - create new folder in app folder like webroot and put files in it
 - use Dispatcher Filters in cakephp : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html
and ....